# Contact Tracing in Python - working with timeseries

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series

Let's say I have timeseries data (time on the x-axis, coordinates on the y-z plane.

Given a seed set of infected users, I want to fetch all users that are within distance `d` from the points in the seed set within `t` time. This is basically just contact tracing.

What is a smart way of accomplishing this?

The naive approach is something like this:

```
points_at_end_of_iteration = []
for p in seed_set:
    other_ps = find_points_t_time_away(t)
    points_at_end_of_iteration += find_points_d_distance_away_from_set(other_ps)
```

What is a smarter way of doing this - preferably keeping all data in RAM (though I'm not sure if this is feasible). Is Pandas a good option? I've been thinking about [Bandicoot](http://bandicoot.mit.edu/) as well, but it doesn't seem to be able to do that for me.

Please let me know if I can improve the question - perhaps it's too broad.

**Edit:**

I think the algorithm I presented above is flawed.

Is this better:

```
for user,time,pos in infected_set:
    info = get_next_info(user, time) # info will be a tuple: (t, pos)
    intersecting_users = find_intersecting_users(user, time, delta_t, pos, delta_pos) # intersect if close enough to the user's pos/time
    infected_set.add(intersecting_users)
    update_infected_set(user, info) # change last_time and last_pos (described below)
```

`infected_set` I think should actually be a hashmap `{user_id: {last_time: ..., last_pos: ...}, user_id2: ...}`

One potential problem is that the users are treated independently, so the next timestamp for user2 may be hours or days after user1.

Contact tracing may be easier if I interpolate so that every user has information for every time point (say ever hour) though that would increase the amount of data by a huge amount.

**Data Format/Sample**

```
user_id = 123
timestamp = 2015-05-01 05:22:25
position = 12.111,-12.111 # lat,long
```

There is one csv file with all the records:

```
uid1,timestamp1,position1
uid1,timestamp2,position2
uid2,timestamp3,position3
```

There is also a directory of files (same format) where each file corresponds to a user.

records/uid1.csv
records/uid2.csv

Comment: Are you able to provide a data sample?

Comment: @toasteez Sure, I will update.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: How do you define contact between two users? Is it when they are at the exact same position at the exact same time? Or is there a threshold for the position and/or time?

Comment: There is a threshold. That is what the `delta_t` and `delta_pos` is for. It gives a range.

Comment: Is `numpy` an option? It would really make sense as you are working on large timeseries/xy vectors.

Comment: @matjazzz144 It is. But one problem is that I have too much data to load in memory at once, so I'm doing a bunch of file IO (I should probably edit my question to mention that).

Comment: How much data? A good idea would be to sort by time over different files, if that's not the case already. You probably want to calculate at each time increment starting at the earliest time and load files in memory as you go along. Also if the time increment is large for a particular person you probably want to interpolate or the probability of infection will be relatively low :) [made a mistake and posted this as an answer. sorry]

Comment: @matjazzz144 Yes the data is sorted by time. After filtering the data and putting it in Bandicoot format (the module I'm using), every user has their own csv file and there are a little under 70K files. The largest user file is 240MB (though it will probably be filtered out). Overall, size varies from 10KB to 1.5MB (excluding the outliers). However I am loading the user object Bandicoot creates for me, which contains a lot more information. I was thinking about interpolating, but there are several challenges that make this not straightforward.

Comment: Once you get your data structured, you're almost done. `pytables` comes to mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution with interpolate:

```
# i would use a shelf (a persistent, dictionary-like object,
# included with python).
import shelve

# hashmap of clean users indexed by timestamp)
# { timestamp1: {uid1: (lat11, long11), uid12: (lat12, long12), ...},
#   timestamp2: {uid1: (lat21, long21), uid2: (lat22, long22), ...},
#   ...
# }
#
clean_users = shelve.open("clean_users.dat")

# load data in clean_users from csv (shelve use same syntax than
# hashmap). You will interpolate data (only data at a given timestamp
# will be in memory at the same time). Note: the timestamp must be a string

# hashmap of infected users indexed by timestamp (same format than clean_users)
infected_users = shelve.open("infected_users.dat")

# for each iteration
for iteration in range(1, N):

    # compute current timestamp because we interpolate each user has a location
    current_timestamp = timestamp_from_iteration(iteration)

    # get clean users for this iteration (in memory)
    current_clean_users = clean_user[current_timestamp]

    # get infected users for this iteration (in memory)
    current_infected_users = infected_user[current_timestamp]

    # new infected user for this iteration
    new_infected_users = dict()

    # compute new infected_users for this iteration from current_clean_users and
    # current_infected_users then store the result in new_infected_users

    # remove user in new_infected_users from clean_users

    # add user in new_infected_users to infected_users

# close the shelves
infected_users.close()
clean_users.close()
```

Second solution without interpolate:

```
# i would use a shelf (a persistent, dictionary-like object,
# included with python).
import shelve

# hashmap of clean users indexed by timestamp)
# { timestamp1: {uid1: (lat11, long11), uid12: (lat12, long12), ...},
#   timestamp2: {uid1: (lat21, long21), uid2: (lat22, long22), ...},
#   ...
# }
#
clean_users = shelve.open("clean_users.dat")

# load data in clean_users from csv (shelve use same syntax than
# hashmap). Note: the timestamp must be a string

# hashmap of infected users indexed by timestamp (same format than clean_users)
infected_users = shelve.open("infected_users.dat")


# for each iteration (not time related as previous version)
# could also stop when there is no new infected users in the iteration
for iteration in range(1, N):

    # new infected users for this iteration
    new_infected_users = dict()

    # get timestamp from infected_users
    for an_infected_timestamp in infected_users.keys():

        # get infected users for this time stamp 
        current_infected_users = infected_users[an_infected_timestamp]

        # get relevant timestamp from clean users
        for a_clean_timestamp in clean_users.keys():
            if time_stamp_in_delta(an_infected_timestamp, a_clean_timestamp):

                # get clean users for this clean time stamp
                current_clean_users = clean_users[a_clean_timestamp]

                # compute infected users from current_clean_users and
                # current_infected_users then append the result to
                # new_infected_users

        # remove user in new_infected_users from clean_users

        # add user in new_infected_users to infected_users

# close the shelves
infected_users.close()
clean_users.close()
```

Comment: `shelve` looks really useful - thanks! One issue is that I'm not interpolating (I mentioned I might, but that would result in way too much data and more importantly, the method of interpolating [in a way that makes sense in my context] isn't that straightforward).

Comment: I have added a version without interpolate. I think it may work

Comment: When I `open` the data, does `shelve` load it all in memory (I thought I saw that mentioned somewhere, but can't find it anymore - doesn't seem to be true the more I search for it), or is the dictionary-like access simply an abstraction for the underlying file IO? Is caching then the main benefit?

Comment: "compute infected users from current_clean_users" - means check that their (infected user and current user) coordinates are close?

Comment: Yes "compute infected users from current_clean_users"  - means check that their (infected user and current user) coordinates are close. The timestamp is already done at this stage

Comment: A shelve use behind the scene a btree on the disk. It's use a cache mecanism and you can use for example infected_users.sync() when you want to flush the cache. You can also use shelve.open(filename, writeback=False) if you want to sync automaticly.  When you get a key from the shelve this one and only this one is loaded in memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Though I haven't tested it out, it looks promising.